# Python: load txt files and form a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a directory full of txt files about apple stocks like this:

Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2012-10-15,632.35,635.13,623.85,634.76,15446500,631.87

I need to get the names of all files that have the format APPL_*.txt, load all files of those names in my Notebook, and concatenate them together to form one data frame of 61 rows and 7 columns. I hope I was clear enough, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('directory')

# loop through files
collector = []
for i in os.listdir():
    if 'AAPL_' in i and i.endswith('.txt'):
        txt_df = pd.read_csv(i, delimiter = ',')
        collector.append(txt_df)
# combine the list of dataframes from your text files
df = pd.concat(collector)
```